# Adding external jar to the eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse-rcp

First I have created the plug-in project using "plug-in from existing jar archive". and I added this plug-in in my eclipse rcp application through "plug-in.xml --> dependencies --> required plugins --> add .

When i doing so and run the application, it not even recognise the eclipse core apis and it throws the error like:

```
!SESSION 2009-08-04 18:50:31.403 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_04
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product File_Explorer.product
Command-line arguments:  -product File_Explorer.product -data D:\Prabakar\Workspace\Eclipse_SDK_Workspace/../runtime-File_Explorer.product -dev file:D:/Prabakar/Workspace/Eclipse_SDK_Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/File_Explorer.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2009-08-04 18:50:34.887
!MESSAGE Product File_Explorer.product could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-08-04 18:50:35.059
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-08-04 18:50:35.059
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:/D:/Installed/IDEs/eclipse_sdk/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.console_1.0.100.v20090520-1905.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.console 2 0 2009-08-04 18:50:35.059
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.configurator_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-08-04 18:50:35.059
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:/D:/Installed/IDEs/eclipse_sdk/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_1.0.100.v20090527-1812.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 2 0 2009-08-04 18:50:35.059
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.configurator_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2009-08-04 18:50:35.059
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use a jar file, create a plugin from it, it won't know the Eclipse API by default.

Either you have to define an RCP application from it (thus creating your entry point), and use it in a RCP target platform, and then you can use most of the Eclipse API.

For detailed description about Eclipse RCP I suggest [the tutorial at vogella.de](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html)